# postgresql fill null values on repeat

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table filled with 1000 last names and a table filled with 100 first names. I want to create a new table with these 1000 last names and 100 first names on repeat. How can I do this in `postgreSQL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this right, you want to list all the 1000 last names and the 100 first names repeating 10 times.

Try something like this:

```
select *
from (
    select l.*,
        row_number() over (order by ?) as rn
    from last_names l
    ) l
join (
    select f.*,
        row_number() over (order by ?) as rn,
        count(*) over () as total_count
    from first_names f
    ) f on mod(l.rn - 1, total_count) = f.rn - 1;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/IAXJN5229)

Comment: is mod necessary?  any other way?